# ef.net core, properties instead of fields

Tags: wpf, entity-framework, ef-core-3.0, wpf-core, wpf-core-3.0

So, we are porting an old wpf app into .net core wpf. As part of the effort we are also moving the data layer to `EF.net core`.

1. Since we use Prism MVVM, within the DI service context we keep a live data context which tracks the entities being shown and edited by user through the wpf front end and via service.
2. In order to implement "undo" functionality, we track the objects using 
   `entity.HasChangeTrackingStrategy(ChangeTrackingStrategy.ChangingAndChangedNotificationsWithOriginalValues);`

On edit, the object gets updated, on Reload() it gets reverted from tracked original values. Object wise, the operations are ok, however, the wpf side of things is not working ok. It seems the ef.net core is a very maladjusted citizen of the wpf application, assuming its the sole beneficiary of INotifyPropertyChanged mechanism. Which is, of course, not true in the slightest for WPF.

1. EF.net does not seem to use properties when loading, reloading etc. It works directly on underlying fields. As a consequence, NotifyPropertyChanged never fires so grid never refreshes with new data, on say `dbContext.Entry(c).Reload();`. So question #1, is there a way to force ef.net to work with properties and not fields?
2. The ef.net implementation of `INotifyPropertyChanged` seems to be flawed. If you invoke PropoertyChanged event on a property, without actually changing it, it will mark the entity as `Modified`, even though it can easily compare original and current value. This prohibits us from manually raising property changed events to control WPF rendering. Not sure how to solve this, or if its even solvable because it only applies to this tracking strategy. I am open to any suggestion on how I can notify WPF elements without riling up ef.net.
3. Determining the state of the object is rather convoluted operation involving `dbContext.Entry(entry).State` which exists outside of any WPF bindings within `DataContext` hierarchy. It makes binding on state virtually impossible (for example to change the background of dirty entries or show Save button, etc). We "solved" it by inheriting all our entity classes from `NotifySetterObject` base class which handles `INotify*` implementation and also keeps `[NotMapped] bool IsDirty` flag. Needless to say, I dislike this heavily, keeping two unlinked state flags sounds like an accident waiting to happen. I am wondering if you encountered similar problem and if you devised a better, more sane, solution.

EF.net seems to have undergone a breaking change transformation from framework ef.net in terms of being only well suited for detached context scenarios (like asp.net). Are we wasting our time here trying to fit this shoe on wpf? Should we maybe focus on a different OR engine more suited to live contexts?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Before trying to address your questions, let me point out some things:

1. You are using EF Core 3.0, which currently is in *preview* (beta), so many things might not work as expected.
2. If by `ef.net` you mean EF6, i.e. the old project you are porting was using EF6, it's not strongly necessary to switch to EF Core - EF6 is also [getting .Net Core support](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/features#ef-63-on-net-core) - a *preview* version [is available here](https://www.nuget.org/packages/EntityFramework/6.3.0-preview7-19363-02).

Now regarding your concrete questions:

1. EF Core *can* use properties, field or both. This is configurable via fluent API at context, entity and property level. Just the EF Core 3.0 default has changed - you can see that in [Breaking Changes - Backing fields are used by default](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-3.0/breaking-changes#backing-fields-are-used-by-default). The link also shows how the get the desired behavior by using

   ```
   .UsePropertyAccessMode(PropertyAccessMode.FieldDuringConstruction)
   ```

on model (all entities), entity (all entity properties) or property (specific entity property) builders.

2. The behavior is explained in the [ChangeTrackingStrategy](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/dotnet/api/microsoft.entityframeworkcore.changetrackingstrategy?view=efcore-2.1) documentation:

> Original values are recorded when the entity raises the `PropertyChanging`. Properties are marked as modified when the entity raises the `PropertyChanged` event.

So it is by design, hence there is nothing you can do about it. But solving #1 eliminates the need of manually raising `PropertyChanged` event, and the two-way binding seem to work flawlessly.

3. I'm not quite sure what exactly are you after here. But starting with v2.1, EF Core provides 2 [State change events](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/what-is-new/ef-core-2.1#state-change-events) on `ChangeTracker` - `Tracked` and `StateChanged`, which (especially the second) can be used to provide state change notifications. But the actual mechanism for that is left for you. For instance, you can use EF Core 2.1+ [entity constructor service injection](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/ef/core/modeling/constructors#injecting-services) feature to inject `DbContext` into entity, which in turn can subscribe to `StateChanged` event and raise `PropertyChanged` for its own unmapped `State` property etc.

Comment: Re the initial comments: We sort of lost that TLC feeling from MS on Framework/EF6, thus we decided on the port of everything into core, we do not want to be caught in bad position. There are also other features in core which will not be back ported into EF6 which we aim to use if possible.

Comment: Re the rest, first off thanks for #1, that does solve things. On 3, we need a way to bind (one way from source) on entity state and receive notification when changed (like INotify*). In theory I can multi-bind to current entity and context and use multibindingconverter to invoke `dbcontext.Entry(e).Status`. But its a one trick pony, if the state changes there is no notification path to cause rebinding.

Comment: But the aforementioned `Context.ChangeTracker.StateChanged` should give you that notification, no?

Comment: I have to check how it works first. If its a single event for all entities (which appears to be) and is invoked for every state change, it will be problematic. If I have 500 rows, and everyo one of them registers a handler, there will be 500 event handlers in the multicast delegate and every state change will invoke 500 handlers. It does not sound like a feasible solution. But I could rework this, have a default handler in constructed context and hae all my entities inherit base class with dirty flag which would be changed by a singular handler.

Comment: Anyway, you have definitely helped me here and pointed me in the right direction, so I will accept your answer.

Comment: You are right that each entity subscribing to state events would be problematic. Which leads me to the following, hopefully better idea. You can make the context subscribe to its own change tracker events. Inside handlers, its has access to both entity instance and state. It could query the entity instance for a specific interface/base class to forward the notification. Just an idea, I'm pretty sure you can make it work :)

Comment: I resolved it on the context factory level :) If context is created with ditry tracking and entity inherits my `EFNotifySetterObject` (which all my entities now do), it updates the dirty flag -> https://pastebin.com/5RuUCZ7f  This gives me one event per context and only when I want it, which works perfectly.

Comment: Yeah, different implementation of the same idea. So EF Core is not that bad at all :)

Comment: Yea, this is something I can use now. Thanks!